# Pathless `url_for` and controllers with multiple resource routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

It's possible to use `link_to` and associated helpers without specifying a URL, path, or route helper; in that case Rails, will generate a URL based on the current view:

```rb
# app/views/files/index.html.erb

<%= link_to "Click me", {clicked: "yes"} %>
# Generates <a href="/files?clicked=yes">Click me</a>
```

(this might be handy for, say, a generic shared partial or helper for sorting or pagination)

It's also possible to have multiple resources pointing to the same Controller - you can distinguish them via a `defaults:` parameter:

```rb
# config/routes.rb

# Handled by FilesController, params[:special] is unset
resources :files 

# Handled by FilesController, params[:special] == true
resources :special_files, controller: "files", defaults: { special: true }
```

If you do *both* these things, then the pathless link on the `/special_files` route still renders as `/files`. Is there a way, by specifying additional options to the second argument of `link_to` for instance, that I can make it link to whichever route was actually used?

Comment: Whats actually happening in your "pathless" link is that it's implicitly calling `url_for(controller: params[:controller], action: params[:action])`. Both of these are special parameters that are set by the router middleware when it matches the request with an action. Can you get it to implicitly do something completely else? Maybe. But I wouldn't want to as there is more likely a simpler and more robust solution to whatever real problem this would solve.

Comment: Yeah, it's likely the correct solution is to split out the Controller in some way. Which is a shame, because the two aren't really doing anything much different, but they do really want to live at different URLs (for internal Reasons). I'll have to choose a good way to extract the common behaviour.

Comment: I have no idea how you came to that conclusion when you can just write your own method to generate URLs dynamically however you want. You just shouldn't hinge everything on the implicit behavior of the link_to methods.

Comment: Obviously I can do that in isolation. The difficulty comes when the rest of the extremely large app is considered, including - as I allude - shared helpers for sorting and pagination. Everything's ultimately rewritable; but if doing so impacts the rest of the codebase, or interferes with a third-party gem (`will_paginate`, say), it becomes trickier.